# JS Window Width / Height Function — Works but Need Some Advice

Tags: javascript

I've built this window height & width display function (similar to the one in Chrome DevTools) in JavaScript. It works like this:

1. If you adjust window width / height it displays the current screen dimensions in the appended textbox.
2. If the window is inactive for 3 seconds, the textbox hides.
3. If you re-adjust the window, it resets the timer (to not cause overlap, in case you re-adjust within 1-2 seconds).

**It works,** this is my 3rd re-write, but I know it can be coded better than this, can someone give me some advice on how to improve my code? I'm still at the rookie stage.

https://jsfiddle.net/kon56edn/

```
var boxText = document.createElement('div');
var boxStyle = boxText.style;

boxStyle.position = 'fixed';
boxStyle.right = 0;
boxStyle.top = 0;
boxStyle.padding = '16px';
boxStyle.zIndex = 999;
boxStyle.fontSize = '22px';
boxStyle.display = 'none';

var timerHandle = setTimeout(3000);

function resetTimer() {
  window.clearTimeout(timerHandle);

timerHandle = setTimeout(function() {

  boxStyle.display = 'none';

 }, 3000);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(timerHandle) {

  boxText.innerText = window.innerWidth + 'px' + ' x ' + window.innerHeight + 'px';
  boxStyle.display = 'block';
  document.body.appendChild(boxText);

  resetTimer();

});
```

I really want to get better at writing clean, modular JS. Any help or perspective is appreciated! :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review questions belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Damn you're right, I didn't even think about that, sorry :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes, mainly doing some heavy lifting on the event handler.
here's a lighter version

```
var box = document.createElement('div');
var timerHandle;

// I would move this to external css if you want cleaner code
box.style.position = 'fixed';
box.style.right = 0;
box.style.top = 0;
box.style.padding = '16px';
box.style.zIndex = 999;
box.style.fontSize = '22px';
box.style.display = 'none';

// Append the box to the view only once! not everytime the event occures
document.body.appendChild(box);

// Handler for when the time is up
function hideBox() {
    box.style.display = 'none';
}

// I would add a throttle function here, search for lodash throttle for example
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    box.innerText = window.innerWidth + 'px' + ' x ' + window.innerHeight + 'px';
    box.style.display = 'block';

    // Reset the timer everytime the event happens
    if (timerHandle) {
        clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        timerHandle = null;
    }

    // Start the timer only when the event happend
    timerHandle = setTimeout(hideBox, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the comments in the code! I knew the event handler was a mess, I can totally see why your version is lighter! I think they will close this down as it belongs in Stackexchange, but I accepted your answer, I hope you still get the credit.